# Transferring data from one class to another

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

search text change.

1. The Main Body in the Main Index will change to the product index in the future.
   2.product index will read the value of the search text.

react native started and I have no idea how to do this. I expect your help.

[enter link description image here](https://ibb.co/g6fN93r)

**main index**

```
            <Headers />
            <Router>
                <Scene>
                    <Scene key="maintabs" tabs={true} hideNavBar tabStyle={{ borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#d2d6dd' }} >
                        {/***************** HOME ****************/}
                        <Scene
                            key="home"
                            title="HOME"
                            lazy
                            iconName={
                                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                                    ? 'ios-home'
                                    : 'md-home'
                            }
                            icon={TabIconx}
                            onPress={() => {

                                Actions.mainsviews({ type: ActionConst.REFRESH });
                            }}>
                            <Scene key="mainsviews" component={BodyIdexs} />
                        </Scene>
                        {/*************** HOME **************/}

                        {/**************** PRODUCT *****************/}
                        <Scene
                            key="products"
                            title="PRODUCTS"

                            iconName={
                                Platform.OS === 'ios'
                                    ? 'ios-apps'
                                    : 'md-apps'
                            }
                            activeT={this.props.focused}
                            icon={TabIconx}
                            onPress={() => {

                                Actions.productsviews({ type: ActionConst.REFRESH });
                            }} >
                            <Scene key="productsviews" component={ProducIdexs} />

                        </Scene>      
                       {/**************** PRODUCT END *****************/}
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
            <Router>
```

do I use an event or a similar structure?